# trying to open an on click element in a new window

Tags: php

I have a button from an embedded piece on a page that links to a form that I want to open things in new window but currently, the page opens inside the embedded piece

Of course, I tried `target=_blank` but that didn't seem to work. I tried `onClick="location.href='embed_newstore.php'"` but that didn't work either.

```
<input type="button" name="op" onclick="document.location.href='embed_newstore.php'" id="edit-submit" value="<?php echo $lang['REQUEST_ADD_STORE']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" style="color:white !important;" target="_blank"/>
```

expected: embed_newstore.php opens in new window/tab

actual: embed_newstore.php opens in the embed application container

Comment: use window.open()

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
onclick="window.open('embed_newstore.php');"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

onclick="window.open('http://localhost/embed_newstore.php');"

**it is only works if button not inside the form tags**